# Localization of wx.DirDialog on Mac OS

Tags: macos, python-2.7, wxwidgets, nsopenpanel

How to localize open dialog/panel on MacOS using Python which uses wx.DirDialog API?
Code:

```
dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, title, style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE)
dlg.ShowModal()
```

I have gone through "http://wxwidgets.info/localization_video/comment-page-1/#comment-403", which has following steps to localize:

- Create simple wxWidgets application
- Extract string constants from source code with poEdit and create .PO file
- Translate string constants with poEdit
- Create message catalog (.MO file) with poEdit
- Apply translation with wxLocale class

But, how do I translate default strings, that are not supplied from my code?

Attached images of wx.DirDialog open dialog and TextEdit application's open dialog for reference.
[image: Open dialog obtained through my app]
[image: Open dialog obtained through TextEdit application]

Comment: what country are you in? If you just run "TextEdit" and hit "Cmd+O" will this dialog be localized? In general wxWidgets (and wxPython) are using native platform controls, so if you OS does not support localization - you won't have it with wx-based application. If you want it see how to add localization to you Mac.

Comment: Also see this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201841.

Comment: Yes, when I hit "Cmd+O" on TextEdit application, this open dialog is localized. Also I have successfully localized my application's context menu items, and other UI items like Window, button, tables as expected.

But the only dialog that is not localized in my app is open dialog, that I use for browsing and selecting a folder using "wx.DirDialog" library.
As in the image, I am able to localize the message in the window that we pass as the argument for wx.DirDialog. 

Is there anything that I should do from my application to localize open dialog's constant's/standard strings?

Comment: please check the trac.wxwidgets.org. I think there is a bug open (an old one - against wxWidgets /not wxPython/) which is about this issue. The ticket has a patch attached, so if you are interested, you can grab the patch, apply it and recompile wxWidgets/wxPython. Let us know how is it.

Comment: Thank you, got the link http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/9659 and it is working as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Indicating the languages that application supports in the bundle's info.plist with "CFBundleLocalizations/Localizations" displays all the items in system language in Open and save process.

Reference link: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/9659